# How can I print out the Memory Address of a variable?

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to print what's behind an &myVariable. I tried NSLog(&myIntVar); but it won't work.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The argument to NSLog needs to be an NSString, so you want

```
NSLog(@"%p", &myIntVar);
```

Comment: Better yet, us @"%p". %x formats an integer value as hexadecimal, whereas %p is specifically for pointers, and additionally pads the hexadecimal representation it prints.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
NSLog(@"%p", &myIntVar);
```

or

```
NSLog(@"%lx", (long)&myIntVar);
```

The first version uses the pointer-specific print format, which assumes that the passed parameter is a pointer, but internally treats it as a long.

The second version takes the address, then casts it to a long integer.  This is necessary for portability on 64-bit platforms, because without the "`l`" format qualifier it would assume that the supplied value is an integer, typically only 32-bits long.

Comment: I'd recommend against the second version, you don't gain anything. %p already works as expected on 32 or 64 bit platforms.

Comment: Apple specifically mention the latter method themselves: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Nslog(@"%x",&myIntVar); %x is for long int
or you can print like Nslog(@"%p",&myIntVar); %p is for pointer